# How to handle MIME Multipart/form-data POST while using jmeter for load testing?

Tags: spring-mvc, jmeter

I've got a problem trying to run a test plan in JMeter which contains a
multipart/form-data POST. For some reason the web server does not respond
with the expected response when JMeter does the POST (which was recorded
with the proxy).
Please tell me the exact configuration to handle it(if any).

Answer (score 2):

As per [Upload and Download Scenarios with Apache JMeter](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-performance-test-upload-and-download-scenarios-apache-jmeter) guide

- Check that “Use multipart/form data for POST” is ticked
- Check that files for upload actually exist in their relative location or use the full paths
- Provide the correct MIME Type

The combination of above should do the trick for you.

If your file upload assumes authenticated user, make sure that you have [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) is present and enabled and in case of any dynamic parameters, like `viewstate` input value or `JSESSIONID` cookie you pass them properly. Use a sniffer tool like [WireShark](http://www.wireshark.org/) to ensure that your request is an exact replica of browser request.

Comment: if i dont upload any file,it throws null pointer exception and file upload is successfull only whn i upload those file which are in jmeter bin directory.

Comment: you need to use full path to file. If you providing just file name it has to be in JMeter's /bin folder or any folder FileServer is configured to read from.

Comment: when i dont upload any file,it shows null pointer exception while using jmeter.let me know the solution if any.my form enc type is of multipart but i dont have to upload files.